# edit for image upload not working cakephp using Qimage

Tags: php, cakephp

Add of image upload is working fine ... but in case of edit there is no upload happening. DB retain old image data. I am using Qimage for file copy.
Controller of image upload

```
public function edit($id=NULL){
            if (!$id) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Movie'));
            }
            $movie = $this->Movie->findById($id);
            if (!$movie) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Movie'));
            }
            if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            $this->Movie->id = $id;
            if(!empty($this->request->data['Movie']['image']['name'])){
                    $data['file']= $this->request->data['Movie']['image'];
                    $data['path']= WWW_ROOT . 'img/';
                    unset($this->request->data['Movie']['image']);
                    $this->request->data['Movie']['image']=$this->Qimage->copy($data);
                    $this->Qimage->resize(array(
                        'width'=>200, 'height'=>300,
                        'file'=>WWW_ROOT . 'img/'.$this->request->data['Movie']['image'],
                        'output'=>WWW_ROOT . 'img/'
                        ));
                }
                else{
                    unset($this->request->data['Movie']['image']);
                }

                if ($this->Movie->saveAll($this->request->data['Movie'])) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Movie has been updated.'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'movies','action' => 'movielist'));
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update movie.'));
                }
            }
            if (!$this->request->data) {
                $this->request->data = $movie;
            }

}
```

please help. 
View of Edit function-

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Movie');?>
<fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Update Movie'); ?></legend>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden')); 
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('about');
        echo $this->Form->file('Movie.image');
        echo $this->Form->input('budget');
        echo $this->Form->submit('Update Movie', array('class' => 'form-submit',  'title' => 'Click here to update the movie')); 
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Comment: Uchit welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). have you tried a minimal working example? What versions are you using?

Comment: ok I will surely look into it. I am using version 2.6.7

Comment: I have tried minimal working example for add not for edit

Comment: Are you sure that ``'output'=>WWW_ROOT . 'img/'`` is okay? Don't you need a full pathname?

Comment: @JvO I also tried that. Its not working. actually WWW_ROOT is working fine for add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are uploading a file, you must tell the Form handler to create the proper HTML. In your edit View, you should start with:

`<?php echo $this->Form->create('Movie', array('type' => 'file'));?>`

I think you did that in your Add view but forgot it here.

Hint: use the same code for both your Add and Edit view by putting the form generation code in a separate file, then include() that snippet of code.

Comment: thnxx .. I missed that :P